# cellForItemAtIndexPath not called but numberOfItemsInSection does

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

This could be a duplicate post but I haven't found the solution.

I'm setting my `UICollectionView` as:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell"
                           bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[_collectionView registerNib: nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"bCell"];
```

(I've tried to set a delegate, without delegate, etcetera).

But then, only the

`- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section` gets called while

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` doesn't.

I've checked the **numberOfItemsInSection** I return, and it's always > 0 (it's exactly 17).

I've checked to call `[_collectionView reloadData];` and nothing happens either.

I've tried different things but I can't make it work.

Furthermore, my `UICollectionView` should be here but it's not:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue?
Thank you.

Comment: have you added "numberofsectionsincollectionview" method..? Please put delegate and datasource methods by this we can help you more.

Comment: `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` will be called only if item exists (i.e. item present for indexPath) and are visible. For instance, what's the size of the cells? Did you put some "space" between them, etc. DO you call `reloadData` in main thread?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! In my case, translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints was mistakenly set to true.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Ok I think this could be useful for future problems with this...

It was because of constraints on the StoryBoard. I don't really understand why that happens, because I just had fixed an horizontal space. I removed the horizontal space as constraint for that View and everything works fine.

Well, let's life flow.

Comment: I was missing a height constraint. Thanks for the hint. Saved me some time for sure. :)

Comment: Ok, I know I need to find a constraint that causes this issue but I can't figure out which constraint to change. Can somebody explain how to look for?

Comment: look for the specific constraints of collectionView. In my case, the top constraint was trying to set distance with an removed element..

Comment: It's bizarre that this still works. :) I literally was pulling my hairs of trying to figure out what the issue was and then after I saw this, just created a height constraint and it started working.

Comment: Thanks you so much!  I think it's kinda stupid for apple to have this issue. Maybe I don't want constraints!!

Comment: After days of debugging, THIS was the issue! Thanks Rafael!

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing me toward this. The issue with my code was that I was setting the collectionView's itemSize height to infinite. 
Side note: CGFloat(212/352) equals 0. CGFloat(212.0/352.0) equals 0.6

Answer (score 25):

I also face same issue and finally got to know that i have passed wrong class object for collectionViewLayout , i change to **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** instead of **UICollectionViewLayout** while creating object for UICollectionView like below its stared calling all delegate method.

```
 collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 0, 400, 40) , collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

Comment: I just spent around 2 hours to -finally- find this mistake, I wish I could read this answer before!

Comment: Wow I wish I read this before as well. Thank you. FYI for anyone else who might have created their `UICollectionView ` programmatically

Comment: Thank you! Two hours of searching and found this!

Answer (score 24):

I meet this problem too. I checked all the possible issues, everything looks ok. Then I tried to changed the reload methods.

`[self.colView reloadData]` -> `[self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:x]];`

Then all things worked. However I still don't understand how.

Comment: What a bug! >:( Thank you for the solution.

Comment: What is the reason for it? Only this worked for me also.

Comment: @frank What is x hear?

Comment: @Muju the section you want to reload.

Comment: Yup, this worked for me too. Very weird. I have a collectionView IBOutlet connected to a UIVIew nib... would love to learn the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 20):

Add this to viewDidLoad:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: The best answer, it wasted me a day.

Comment: while iOS13 fix this bug.

Answer (score 19):

**1. cellForItemAtIndexPath will be called when you return More than 0 Items on numberOfItemsInSection method.**

**2. Check that your UICollectionViewFlowLayout is correct or your own. [UICollectionViewLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html) is abstract class you can't use it directly**

**3. Check the size of the collection view cell & Collection view.**

**4. Try to set your collectionview size by in code.**
[yourCollectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200)];

**5.If any of them NOT works, then kill the XCode & restart . Sometimes it will fix the issue.**

Apple says

The UICollectionViewLayout class is an abstract base class that you subclass and use to generate layout information for a collection view. The job of a layout object is to determine the placement of cells, supplementary views, and decoration views inside the collection view’s bounds and to report that information to the collection view when asked. The collection view then applies the provided layout information to the corresponding views so that they can be presented onscreen.

You must subclass UICollectionViewLayout in order to use it. Before you consider subclassing, though, you should look at the UICollectionViewFlowLayout class to see if it can be adapted to your layout needs.

Comment: I didn't explain it very well, but this is what's regarding with the number: ** I've checked the count I return, and it's always > 0 (it's exactly 17). **

Comment: `collectionViewContentSize` cannot be `.zero`, or else `cellForItemAt` will not be called.

Answer (score 11):

I just found that NONE of cellForItemAtIndexPath gets called (in iOS 10) as long as at least ONE cell has a height of zero.

Disclaimer: sorry if this should have been a comment - not enough reputation.

Comment: It looks like `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` can't return zero if there is postitive `numberOfItemsInSection` for the same section

Answer (score 7):

For me the **cellForItemAtIndexPath** not called for the first time after i set the constraint of the collectionView to 0 and then again setting it to its Actual Size.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionVwHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
 if attachments.count > 0 {

     collectionVwHeightContraint.constant = 100
 }else {

     collectionVwHeightContraint.constant = 0
 }
 // collectionVwHeightContraint is my collectionView height Contraint outlet
```

I solved this by calling:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 4):

Might help somebody else, it could be 2 things:

1. Height of the cell is not calculated properly, so need to check the constraints of the cell.

To fix this, I implemented UICollectionViewLayout's method: 
extension TableViewCellActionItemPageControl: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 414, height: 213) 
}
```

2. Other possibility is: the size of the collection view cell returned is more that the collection view itself. Make sure the height of your cell is smaller than the height of your collective.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was working alternatively.
then I run **reloadData()** on the main thread and the issue fixed.
But later after certain changes again the same issue arose. Finally, I made it like below. Now no issues, I feel **self.view.layoutIfNeeded()** plays a key role

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was to set the correct `itemSize`. My `cellForItemAtIndexPath` was not being called because of the wrong height.

So I set the size at:

```
[self.myCollectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(170, 300)];
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was that my collectionView's container didn't have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I was creating my Collection View programmatically but I had given it `CGRectZero` as its frame. I was laying it out using Auto Layout after `viewDidLoad`. If I lay out the collection view while the view controller is loading, it ends up calling `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with collection view outlet on a storyboard with "standard" constraints (bottom, top, leading, trailing fixed to inner view).

I solved in this way:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = self.collectionView.frame.size
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar problem. The issue was with the numberOfItems in section. 
Your cellForRowAtIndexPath might not be called if either your number of sections or number of rows in section is below zero.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, collectionViewCell's height was greater than CollectionView height.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @frank answer: (swifty answer)

```
extension UICollectionView {
   func reloadFirstSection() {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section) )
    }
}
```

and then instead of `collectionView.reloadData()` call `collectionView.reloadFirstSection()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I messed up with my custom cell label constraints. Verify your constraints once again.

Answer (score 0):

**reza_khalafi** answer worked for me, i am using Xcode 11 and swift 4.2.
swift 4.2 version of reza's answer.

add this on viewDidLoad

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```