# Custom Collection View is not showing up

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm working on an app that'll have a range of images and the collectionview is not showing up at all. I was following [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts) article, which I translated to C#.

[here](https://github.com/eman1986/MosaicCollectionLayoutXamarin/archive/master.zip) is an example app I made to show a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

When I run through the code, `GetCell` in the collection source isn't firing which I know is the problem, but I don't know *why* it's not firing and I'm simply at a lost on what I'm missing.

Comment: I was also lost when checking your project. I think the problem is probably caused by the custom layout. Maybe you can try a default UICollectionViewFlowLayout to see if it works. I will go back to check it later and update you if I find anything. And here are some links may help: [cellforitematindexpath-not-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804937/cellforitematindexpath-not-called-but-numberofitemsinsection-does/40448382) and [cellforitematindexpath-is-not-being-called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668781/uicollectionviews-cellforitematindexpath-is-not-being-called)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I disabled the custom layout and it's still not showing up, I'm going to try not using the xib files and see if I get better results, the article I was looking at didn't use them so maybe I'm not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it again today and I can make sure that the problem is caused by the `MosaicCollectionLayout`.

What I did today is that I removed your `collectionView` and add a new `collectionView`, then I **add Constrains to it with a fixed height and width**(to make sure it appears even if there is no data), then I change the layout to **FlowLayout**, it works, here is the screenshot:

[image]

After that, I changed the layout back to `MosaicCollectionLayout`, I get an exception in the line             `_cachedAttributes.Reverse(lastIndex.Row, firstMatchIndex.Value);` inside the method `LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect`.

I checked the article and did not find a solution yet. Maybe there is some mistakes in the codes translated from `swift` to `C#`. So the problem is not related to the `xib`, please check the code in the method `LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect`.You can also try add Constrains  to your collectionView. Hope these information helps you.

Comment: I got that too, I didn't think it was good practice to set constraints in a stackview, but guess there's exceptions. I see my images now, I'll have to tweak the custom layout, maybe I missed something. In any case thank you so much Jack.